# Add image in footer of the pdf using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, footer

I need a python script which will add an images in the footer of the pdf without affecting the original pdf contents.
images should be present over all the pages of the pdf.
Expection is something similar to the images below:

[image]

script should be able to add my image/logo (similar to above images have Pearson logo in the footer of the page)

Note: image and pdf are locally available.

Comment: Show what you've tried. This is not a place to ask scripts for free

Comment: First of all you need to try with your own , because StackOverflow is not a place where you can just say what you want and community will write it down for you. You should first try to do something yourself, and then, based on what you failed to do, post it here to help you, not to write the code for you.

If you will try with your own , I will post an answer down to this post with full solution, so, go ahead ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [footer](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/footer/index.html) of PyFPDF?

Also [image](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html) of PyFPDF allows to add an image by local path or by URL, so maybe you could use both together.

Comment: please insert the content from the links cited into the answer, as links break and may become redundant for future users.